# How to active the windows opened in linux one by one using shell?

Tags: linux, shell, screenshot

The linux system I'm using is RHEL. There are many windows opened in current workspace and there is only one window that is activated. So, my questions are:

1. How can I  activate the windows one by one using shell?
2. How can I take screenshots(using import or gnome-screenshot) of many windows using script shells.

Thank you.

Comment: The `scrot` command saves a screenshot in the current working directory. You might be able to use `wmctrl` to close and open windows in your window manager. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I want to take screenshots for every window using shell commands, but import or gnome-screenshot can only take a screenshot for the activated window. I can't install wmctrl because of no access to root or internet in my company. Do you have any idea to activate the windows one by one using shell commands so that every window activated can be taken. Thank you.